# Get Site URL using Keyword query Search api

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search-api

I want to get Site URL using Keyword Query power shell..

Below are properties(b and **lastmodifiedtime**) im retrieving using keyword query ..likewise i want to get Site URL using below approach,how can i get?

Can anyone help me in this?

```
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Created")
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("LastModifiedTime")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current web URL, you can use the `SPWebUrl` managed property.

To get the current site collection, you can use the `SPSiteUrl` managed property.

So, append the below code as to your code:

```
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SPWebUrl")  // to get SP Web Url
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SPSiteUrl") // to get SP Site Url
```